# Azure VPN Client not working:Server did not respond properly to VPN Control Packets

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

**Project:**
I have created a VPN GW in Azure. A p2S vpn GW is working when connecting using a Mac.
With my Mac, I am connecting using a child certificate and the VPN client in the networking settings.
The RootCA certificate is correctly installed in Azure vpn gw.
We are using certificate authentication - not Active Directory.

**My Goal**
My goal is to make the windows client work with the Azure VPM GW as a p2s client (same as my Mac - which works flawlessly).

**The Problem**

For windows, I install the client certificate; but the the VPN connection does not work when using either the Azure VPN Client or the OpenVPN client.

**The Question:**
Do I need to add/install the Azure VPN Client app in Enterprise Applications, within Azure AD, to use the azure vpn client? What about the OpenVPN App?

I noticed that in the Azure Tenant the Azure VPN Client app isn't installed as an Enterprise App.

**The Error Messages:**

when using openvpn app:

```
2022-10-08 00:49:48 OpenSSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
2022-10-08 00:49:48 OpenSSL: error:140AD009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:PEM lib
2022-10-08 00:49:48 MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
2022-10-08 00:49:48 Cannot load inline certificate file
2022-10-08 00:49:48 Exiting due to fatal error
```

When using the azure vpn client app:

```
08‎/‎10‎/‎2022‎ ‎08‎:‎09‎:‎30: Dialing VPN connection myconnection name, 
Status = Server did not respond properly to VPN Control Packets. 
Session State: TLS handshake in progress
```

Comment: Do you have the root certificate’s public key installed locally on the Windows client?